# Git Flow: creating, testing, and deploying "feature" branches

Tags: git, version-control, staging, git-flow, feature-branch

I've been using git-flow at my company for a little while now and have come across a certain situation various times that boggles me.  I'm trying to figure out a best practice to integrate new features to an existing published site via git-flow, where I will need to test these features and then publish them in separate groupings.

I have set up both a staging and production site.  I deploy from my develop branch to the staging site and run a git-flow release when my develop branch looks good and I want to deploy my changes from master to the production site.  This works fine as long as I can publish all of my changes all at once.  I have recently had many requests from clients to publish change orders in chunks - meaning I will be working on 4 features and they will want 2 of those features published in 1 week and the other 2 in 2 weeks.  I figured that just using git-flow feature branches and "finishing" the branches that need to be published together would solve my issues, but it has left me with many more questions

When I create a feature branch for each of the new features, I find many times that I need to use some css or js that I had committed to another feature branch (because it also pertained to that branch).  I also have a feeling that I'm going to have to deal with a lot of merge conflicts when I git-flow "finish" these branches back into develop (because their commits share a lot of the same files).  The client also wants to see an active version of all of the changes that I'm making, and when I have them siloed into different feature branches, I'm not sure how to show them together unless I merge or rebase them into the develop branch and push to the staging site.  This would ruin my opportunity to publish them in batches.  I thought about maybe creating another branch for testing and rebase my feature branches on this branch, but I'm not sure if that will solve my issues because my feature branches are still isolated when I'm working on them.

I can't seem to find any workflows that will allow me to meet these requirements, so I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You can always git checkout <branch_name> -- <paths> to get one or some files from another branch into your current branch.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  While this helps out, I was hoping that I was missing the mark with my workflow and that there was a different workflow that would work better suite my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did some research in aims of solving the same issue and settled on a "branch per feature" strategy. The name suggests much of the strategy, but here are some great articles that describe it in detail:

http://www.acquia.com/blog/pragmatic-guide-branch-feature-git-branching-strategy

https://github.com/affinitybridge/git-bpf/wiki/Branch-per-feature-process

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you @rjhilgefort.  I'm going to give this a try on a project and see how it works out.